# Why do I get these warnings?

Tags: c, shared-memory, compiler-warnings

The compiler showed the following warnings for the following code segment. Please help me correct it.

> if((tmp_n = (struct dot *)shmat(shm_net, NULL, 0)) == (int *) -1) { }
>   warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]

Its a C program, this code segment is for attaching a shared memory segment to a pointer **tmp_n which is of the type struct dot.

struct dot {int weight; int tmv;};

Comment: I'm not sure how much clearer that warning message could be. You're comparing distinct pointer types without casting them to a common type first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
if((tmp_n = (struct dot *)shmat(shm_net, NULL, 0)) == (void *) -1) { }
```

and look at the [man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat), it states:

```
Return Value
On success shmat() returns the address of the attached shared memory segment; 
on error (void *) -1 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the cause of the error.
```

Comment: But (int *) -1 was working in my other program without any warnings. Maybe I wrote it there by mistake in the first place, but since it was working, and I have been using it for so long, I forgot to look up the manual when this happen.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast `-1` to the same pointer type as the variable you're comparing with:

```
if((tmp_n = (struct dot *)shmat(shm_net, NULL, 0)) == (struct dot *) -1) { }
```